# how can i get only one of the href using beautifulsoup if there are two href in the same line?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get the href using beautifulsoup from these html code,

```
<a href="first_url" class="class" href="2nd_url" style="15px;">text</a>
```

From here, I want to get `first_url`

But using beautifulsoup,

```
for link in soup.find_all('a',{'class':"class"}): 
            print(link.get('href'))
```

I get output `2nd_url`

Comment: use re `"\K[^"]*`

Answer (score 2):

The tag has two `href=` attributes defined, which isn't valid. But, if run BeautifulSoup's `diagnose()` function on it, it produces:

```
data = '''<a href="first_url" class="class" href="2nd_url" style="15px;">text</a>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.diagnose import diagnose

diagnose(data)
```

Prints:

```
Diagnostic running on Beautiful Soup 4.8.1
Python version 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
Found lxml version 4.4.1.0
Found html5lib version 1.0.1

Trying to parse your markup with html.parser
Here's what html.parser did with the markup:
<a class="class" href="2nd_url" style="15px;">
 text
</a>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to parse your markup with html5lib
Here's what html5lib did with the markup:
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <a class="class" href="first_url" style="15px;">
   text
  </a>
 </body>
</html>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to parse your markup with lxml
Here's what lxml did with the markup:
<html>
 <body>
  <a class="class" href="first_url" style="15px;">
   text
  </a>
 </body>
</html>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to parse your markup with lxml-xml
Here's what lxml-xml did with the markup:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a class="class" href="2nd_url" style="15px;">
 text
</a>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

We see, that if we use `lxml` or `html5lib` parser, the `href=` will be `first_url`. `html.parser` will give us `2nd_url`.

So:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
print(soup.a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
first_url
```

Comment: As a reference, the HTML spec specifically defines "There must never be two or more attributes on the same start tag whose names are an ASCII case-insensitive match for each other." https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2  . So this tag on the question is not valid by the definition

Comment: A tag cannot have two attributes of same name, that I what i knew as well until I came across the source code of a particular website. I was trying to crawl into the website when I faced the problem.